# How to delete rows based on condition in embedded data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, rows, drop

I am working with the [MarketMatching package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MarketMatching/vignettes/MarketMatching-Vignette.html) in R.

MarketMatching gives a list of 5 comparison Markets for my target Market.
However, I want to remove specific markets from this list.

The MarketMatching object looks like this in R studio:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqNbU.png)

1. Level 1: mm is a list[5]
2. Level 2: BestMatches is a list[5x8](S3: data.frame)
3. Level 3: BestControl is a character[5]

I tried it like this (where 'mm' is the object described above), 'BestControl' is a column with values "PL", "FI", "NG", "GH", "RU". So I want to delete GH and NG from that list.

```
active_campaigns <- c("GH", "NG")
mm$BestMatches <- mm$BestMatches[!(BestControl %in% active_campaigns),]
```

Out:

```
Error in BestControl %in% active_campaigns : object 'BestControl' not found
```

In other words:
How can I access a column of a dataframe that is embedded in a list to drop rows there?

Comment: It would be `mm$BestControl` if the column 'BestControl' is in `mm` dataset.  But, your code may be incorrect (`length` difference) as your are assigning `BestMatches` subset to the whole dataset column.

Comment: thnx for you quick response! Regardless of what I assign the output to (that I can easily change), I am looking for the right code to access the column.
```mm$BestControl``` returns ```NULL```. Please see the image I attached for clarification of the object structure

Answer (score 1):

You can subset the rows you want (i.e. no character from BestControl within active_campaigns).

```
# 1- Create a function for testing boolean "not within"
'%!in%' <- function(x,y)!('%in%'(x,y))

# 2- Subset the string not within active_campaigns
mmSubset <- subset(mm$BestMatches, BestControl %!in% active_campaigns)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this does exactly what I need :)